# How to add additional disk configuration of a GCP VM while creating it using Packer image on RHEL7

Tags: google-cloud-platform, disk, packer

I was working on automating VM creation on GCP using a packer image.

But I got an issue when adding an additional disk there is no such option through packer configuration as it is only has the option to create boot(os-disk).

Kindly help me in fixing how to add additional disk for a VM through packer image on RHEL 7 OS.

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: This was solved by adding shell script to create additional disk while running packer script and calling this script under provisioner section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by adding a shell script to create additional disk while running packer script and calling this script under the provisioner section.

Answer (score 3):

GCE images only supports one disk. See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74106832 for a open feature request to support this.